# What is the current version of the 802.11r standard

Tags: 802.11

I'm looking for WiFi mesh standards (802.11s, 802.11r, 802.11k, 802.11v).  For example I have found 802.11r-2008 on IEEE's site ([here](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.11r-2008.html)).  The page says that the standard is superceded, but it doesn't point to *what* superceded it.  I have searched for 802.11r-2009 through 802.11r-2016 and come up short.  Any idea what's going on with this standard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Any idea what's going on with this standard?

It was superceded by 802.11-2012.

> In 2007, task group TGmb was authorized to "roll up" many of the
>   amendments to the 2007 version of the 802.11 standard. REVmb or
>   802.11mb, as it was called, created a single document that merged ten amendments (802.11k, **r**, y, n, w, p, z, v, u, s) with the 2007 base
>   standard. In addition much cleanup was done, including a reordering of
>   many of the clauses.  **Upon publication on March 29, 2012, the new
>   standard was referred to as IEEE 802.11-2012.**

[GET IEEE 802®: LOCAL AND METROPOLITAN AREA NETWORK STANDARDS - This is a link to fill out a form](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf)

[802.11-2012](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#802.11-2012)

[IEEE Website Page](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.11-2012.html)

Comment: You got there faster :)

Answer (score 4):

#### Any idea what's going on with this standard?

It has been **incorporated** into **802.11-2012**.

> 802.11-2012 Specific requirements Part 11: Wireless LAN Medium Access Control (MAC) and Physical Layer (PHY) Specifications

...

> This revision gives users, in one document, the IEEE 802.11 standard for wireless local area networks (WLANS) with all the amendments that have been published to date.

...

> The current revision, IEEE Std 802.11-2012, incorporates the following
>   amendments into the 2007 revision:
>
> ...
>
> - IEEE Std 802.11r™-2008: Fast Basic Service Set (BSS) Transition (Amendment 2)

...

Source [802.11-2012 Specific requirements Part 11: Wireless LAN Medium Access Control (MAC) and Physical Layer (PHY) Specifications](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee802/download/802.11-2012.pdf)

Note:

- PDF can be downloaded from the above link.

Comment: Rather than ... you can use <%%>

Answer (score 0):

I ran across these IEEE links where 802.11-2012 (maintenance ceased) has been superseded by:

[802.11-2016 Standard](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.11-2016.html) (Currently Maintained)

Which has in turn been superseded by:

[802.11ai-2016 Standard](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.11ai-2016.html) (Currently Maintained)